# Android TextView.setID(int) programatically not working

Tags: android, textview, int

```
 private void displayWordsList() {
    this.wordsList.removeAllViews();
    int i = (int) (0.5f + (3.0f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    int i2 = (int) (0.5f + (2.0f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    TextView textView = null;
    TextView textView2;
    Word word;
    View textView3;
    LayoutParams layoutParams;
    View view;
    if (findViewById(R.id.words) instanceof ScrollView) {
        Iterator it = this.gridView.getWords().iterator();
        int i3 = 100;
        textView2 = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            word = (Word) it.next();
            if (!word.found) {
                textView3 = new TextView(this);
                textView3.setTextSize(15.0f);
                textView3.setText(word.toString());
                textView3.setGravity(17);
                textView3.setPadding(i, i2, i, i2);
                textView3.setTextColor(Color.argb(MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK, 51, 51, 51));
                layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-2, -2);
                if (i3 == 100) {
                    layoutParams.addRule(11);
                    layoutParams.addRule(10);
                    textView3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    textView3.setId(i3);
                    view = textView3;
                } else {
                    layoutParams.addRule(11);
                    layoutParams.addRule(3, textView2.getId());
                    textView3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    textView3.setId(i3);
                    view = textView3;
                }
                this.wordsList.addView(textView3);
                i3++;
                textView2 = view;
            }
        }
```

this is my cross word game displayWordList.java, textView3.setId(i3); when i try setId(i3) means (int i3=100;) getting error like "Expected resource type of id" in Android Studio any help..

Comment: What you want to use that ID for?

Comment: for my Cross word puzzle game

Comment: I mean what for exactly?To differentiate the TextViews?

Comment: what is the error and try final int i3=100;

Comment: yes, its with gridView

Comment: Ok well, you can use the Tag, instead of the ID. Try differentiating the textViews via Tags. textView.setTag(); You can use the ID too I guess, but I'd say this is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Create file inside your res-values folder. Give it name like ids.xml.
Put this inside your file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <item type="id" name="your_desire_name"/>
</resources>
```

Now you can reference to it:

```
textView3.setId(R.id.your_desire_name);
```

In addition your logic won't work because you didn't initialized "textView3" so it will be null.

Comment: Why you want the id to be this number? better approach is to let the system manage the ids of the Views as I suggested.